# Searching for the amount of integers in multiple ArrayLists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have been thinking about this, but i havent been able to come up with a solution.

I have 9 ArrayLists, which can have Integers from 1 to 10.

What i want to do is: 
Find 2 Numbers(from 1 to 10), that occur in **exactly** 2 of these ArrayLists( Must be the same Array. For Example, the number 2 and 3 both appear only in List1 and List)4. Preferably also know in which ArrayLists these numbers occured.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far ? Where are you stuck ? what specific problem do you face ?

Comment: If you created a Map<Integer,List<List<Integer>> keyed by the "Number" (1-10) then iterated over your array lists and, for each number, added the list, then you'd just have to scan the value set for lists of size 2, those would each contain lists of your two lists (Sorry about the overuse of the word "List", Hopefully the generic definition will help you figure out what I mean.

Comment: Just managed to understand how maps work, it all makes sense now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One method:

First: Create a `Map<Integer, BitSet>`.  Call it `m`.
Next: Iterate through the 9 `ArrayLists` that you have.  For each number `n` that you encounter in array #`a`:

```
m.putIfAbsent(n, new BitSet(9));  // Make there the number has a BitSet to start
m.get(n).set(a);  // Set the bit indicating number n is in array a
```

After that, you just need to look for two `BitSets` in your `Map` having `cardinality() == 2` and are `BitSet.equals()` equal to each other.